# Why am I missing types on Apollo-angular mutation?

Tags: apollo-client, apollo-angular

I am trying to understand the Apollo client in an Angular client. The following code gives me no typings:

```js
fireMutation() {
  this.apollo.mutate<{foo: string}>({
    mutation: gql`some mutation {}`,
    variables: {}
  }).subscribe(v => {
    // No typings on v.
    return;   
  });
}
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2795) on Github, but it's apparently not related to the issue I'm facing.

I have created a Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/apollo-no-typings-on-mutation), to make it easy for you to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Github comment](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4170#issuecomment-477857406), I found the solution.

The fix was to install graphql types: `npm i @types/graphql --save-dev`.

I updated the stackblitz, and it now works

[image: working types apollo/mutation]

Many thanks to [ekron](https://github.com/ekron).